# How to fork opensource project without violating licence?

Tags: maven-2, nsis, fork

I want to fork Maven NSIS plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/index.html at BitBucket. Codehous project seems to be dead. How should I behave to craete legal fork of it?

Comment: did you fork it? i can't find it...

Comment: It was in far 2011. I don't remember. ( I even can't recall why was I asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately([1](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/license.html)) doesn't claim what licence it has, but after checking out their code from svn, the header in the file `NsisCompileMojo.java` says:

```
 * Copyright 2008 Codehaus
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
```

The Apache licence is quite permissive; you can easily fork of your project, but need to keep the original copyright notices of the original authors. More details can be found a Wikipedia([2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License)) (apache.org seems to be down at the moment).

But long story short: Fork.

Edit: One more hint: The Freedom Task Force, an institution of the Free Software Foundation Europe, will be able to help you if you still have legal doubts: http://fsfe.org/projects/ftf/

Answer (score 0):

As usual: I am not a lawyer and you should really get one, if you want proper legal advice. Anything else is just guesswork.

I don't see a license specified anywhere, which makes it hard to do: if no license is specified, that means that you have very limited rights, almost everywhere in the world. And no: the source code being publicly viewable **doesn't** automagically change that!

So unless you can contact the original authors to clarify that for you, you can just as easily assume that it is a closed-source project.